# Doctrine One-To-Many Self-referencing dont work

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

Please for help. I'm trying to do one to many entity in my application, i read a documentation of doctrine. I have my MenuItem class, which have one to one Relations with Page table and many to many relations with table menu. I have to get a tree menu, so MenuItem class have id (as child for me) and parent, but after update schema its dont work, my parent field in database still is not a Foreign key. Here is my MenuItem.php class code:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * MenuItem
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="menu_item")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\MenuItemRepository")
 */
class MenuItem
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MenuItem", mappedBy="parentId")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", length=255, unique=true, nullable=true)
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="parent", type="integer", nullable=true)
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MenuItem", inversedBy="id")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $parentId;

    /**
     * Set url
     *
     * @param string $url
     *
     * @return MenuItem
     */
    public function setUrl($url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrl()
    {
        return $this->url;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return MenuItem
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Menu", mappedBy="menuitems")
     */
    private $menus;
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->menus = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->id = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add menu
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Menu $menu
     *
     * @return MenuItem
     */
    public function addMenu(\AppBundle\Entity\Menu $menu)
    {
        $this->menus[] = $menu;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove menu
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Menu $menu
     */
    public function removeMenu(\AppBundle\Entity\Menu $menu)
    {
        $this->menus->removeElement($menu);
    }

    /**
     * Get menus
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getMenus()
    {
        return $this->menus;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Page")
     */
    private $page;

    /**
     * Set page
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Page $page
     *
     * @return MenuItem
     */
    public function setPage(\AppBundle\Entity\Page $page = null)
    {
        $this->page = $page;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get page
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Page
     */
    public function getPage()
    {
        return $this->page;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set parent
     *
     * @param integer $parent
     *
     * @return MenuItem
     */
    public function setParentId($parentId)
    {
        $this->parentId = $parentId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get parent
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getParentId()
    {
        return $this->parentId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to use this:

```
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    //other fields

    /**
     * One MenuItem has Many MenuItems.
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MenuItem", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    private $children;

    /**
     * Many MenuItems have One MenuItem.
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MenuItem", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $parent;
```

I have removed relation inside $id field and added `children` field

Comment: Thanks for edit my post. Does it make sens to have 3 id ? main id, parent id and child id ?

Comment: I have used this solution and It can be useful, you have one id and two foreign key nullable, you can get parent menuItem and children menuItem if  they exist

Comment: Now i have a doctrine Mapping error given by this class, this error was:
- The association AppBundle\Entity\MenuItem#children refers to the owning side field AppBundle\Entity\MenuItem#parent which is not defined as association, but as field.
- The association AppBundle\Entity\MenuItem#children refers to the owning side field AppBundle\Entity\MenuItem#parent which does not exist.

Comment: Have you launch bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force ? Consider to delete the cache!

Comment: yes, and have "nothing to update" answer, php bin/console cache:clear is enough to clear cache? sorry but im new in symfony and thats my first project so meybe i missed something important ? my other relations work fine.

Comment: try to delete manually the folder inside cache directory and retry, the database need to change a little bit with this edit

Comment: Unfortunetely still no update for database, trying to clear cache by clear:cache and manualy (directory var/cache ) What can be wrong?

Comment: Ok, as i suppose i dont know why but i leave a part of doctrine where i define a ORM field, after delete and do exactly like you write everything is ok. Many Thanks

Comment: Glad to help you! @Anamesh

Answer (score 1):

If you find in your entities `parent` and `child` properties - time to try doctrine GEDMO extension. You can find more on the 
[Official bundle page](https://packagist.org/packages/gedmo/doctrine-extensions). 
Try the doctrine Tree extension - it provides completed mapping for you tree. Very powerful feature!

Comment: I will try it in my next project :)